# Full join on multiple columns not working - mySQL 5.7.36 on wampserver64

Tags: mysql, wamp, outer-join

I have 2 tables (Table_1 and Table_2) that I would like to merge into a new table:

Table_1:

| Variable_A | Variable_B | Variable_C | Variable_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Table_2:

| Variable_A | Variable_B | Variable_E | Variable_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

And I would like to get this new table:

Table_3:

| Variable_A | Variable_B | Variable_C | Variable_D | Variable_E | Variable_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 6 | NULL | NULL | 7 | 8 |

I have tried the following sql command:

```
"CREATE TABLE table_3  
     SELECT 
     *
      FROM table_1 
       FULL JOIN table_2     
          USING (Variable_A, Variable_B);"
```

I expected to see:

| Variable_A | Variable_B | Variable_C | Variable_D | Variable_E | Variable_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 6 | NULL | NULL | 7 | 8 |

What actually resulted:

This got me an empty table with column names Variable_A, Variable_B, Variable_C, Variable_D, Variable_E and Variable_F - the union of the variable names.

I am guessing that the "SELECT *" is where the issue lies. Perhaps I should also select from table_2?

```
Special bonus question:
"Is there a way to automate this so that SQL by itself uses the common variables?".
```

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to achieve your goal:

```
CREATE TABLE table_3
SELECT *, NULL AS Variable_E, NULL AS Variable_F FROM Table_1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Variable_A, Variable_B,NULL,NULL,Variable_E,Variable_F FROM Table_2;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table_3;
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Variable_A | Variable_B | Variable_C | Variable_D | Variable_E | Variable_F |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|          1 |          2 |          3 |          4 |       NULL |       NULL |
|          5 |          6 |       NULL |       NULL |          7 |          8 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```